# How to pull a value from a table with repeated headers using multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have an odd data set that I'm trying to pull data from. The data set looks something like this:

[image: screenshot of table]

I'm trying to get the data in the green cell. Input variables are:

- david
- blue

I want to get the value of the cell that matches the input variables AND where "date" (column B) is the largest for david AND the value is not null. E.g. Not the red cells.

I need to get values for all name/color variations. This would be the table I want to fill (and the values that would be the right values):

[image]

Caveat: This table is created by a Google survey, so the solution needs to account for n rows and n columns and variation in the rows and headers (new names and colors added).

I'm open to a function or a query or creating a helper sheet that somehow aggregates the data in a more search-friendly manner.

I've considered an array formula that iterates through an evaluation of the columns that match the input variable (blue in this case). But I'm not facile enough with arrays to get anywhere with that.

Google sheet with example table can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yYMxaU3iIlmtXrsAITijmjC1zE8VXGPOiu7EbV0O_w8/copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,filter(C2:N,C1:N1=Q1),
     Δ,sortn(filter({A2:B,Σ},A2:A=P1,byrow(Σ,lambda(Γ,counta(Γ)))<>0),1,,2,0),
       index(--query(to_text(tocol(Δ,1)),"offset 2")))
```

- *also it will o/p additional values for this sample scenario if in case there's numbers in cells* `D3 and/or L3`

[image]

***Updated formula:***

```
=iferror(let(Σ,filter($C$2:$P,$C$1:$P$1=U$9),
     Δ,tocol(sortn(filter({$A$2:$B,Σ},$A$2:$A=$T10,byrow(Σ,lambda(Γ,counta(Γ)))<>0),1,,2,0),1),
     index(query(to_text(Δ), "offset "&(counta(to_text(Δ))-1)))))
```

Comment: Brilliant! I have no idea how to read the function, but it works! I updated the requirements slightly (added the solution table that I'm going for). I added $'s to your equation to allow me to construct the table (pasting the equation into all of the table cells). It works great! I extended the "N" column to "O" so that when the table expands and new survey data are entered, current column O will always be the right-most anchor point. Plus, I added an "iferror" at the beginning to handle the case where there is a null in the name/color combo. Thank you!

Comment: What does o/p mean? I added a value to D3 and this error returned: 
"Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in V11." V11 is where I've constructed the solution table in an updated version of my Google sheet. I don't *need* to handle this use case, because my survey will always have one value per row per color. But is there a way to modify to account for this if needed ? If this use case were to happen, I'd want to return the right-most value from the same color in a given row. In the example above, if I put a 9 into D3, I'd want to return the 3 in H3.

Comment: Updated the formula in your sheet to pick the single right-most value match. Please do test it out.

Comment: Works great! But I am noticing that when I try to do computations on the values in the solution table, Google Sheets doesn't seem to be counting them as numbers. I do a sum of a column and get 0. Any idea why?

Comment: just replace the `query` part within the formula to `--query`